# Gnuplot cairolatex does not work

Tags: gnuplot

If I compile a pdf generated with `gnuplot` and the `cairolatex` backend, it compiles with a warning:

```
libxpdf: Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table

libxpdf: Syntax Warning: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
```

and the pdf is weird (no fonts):

[image]

Any idea what is going wrong?

**MWE:**
Generate image with:

```
$ gnuplot -e 'set terminal cairolatex; set output "my-test.pdf"; plot sin(x)'
```

Include with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Test

\includegraphics{my-test}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
I realized that the pdf is also looking the same in a pdf viewer, I don't know what I am missing to also include the text here.

Comment: It is what I was expecting as well, but I cannot see this other file: `$ gnuplot -e 'set terminal cairolatex; set output "my-test.pdf"; plot sin(x)'; ls` gives `my-test.pdf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gnuplot` doc states (p. 247, or http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.5/loc19221.html)

> When using the cairolatex terminal give the name of the TeX file in the `set output` command including the file extension (normally ".tex"). The graph filename is generated by replacing the extension.

so using `set output "my-test.pdf"` is bound to fail.

With

```
set term cairolatex
set encoding utf8
set output "my-test.tex"
p sin(x)
```

then from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\begin{document}
\input{my-test}
\end{document}
```

you get as expected

[image]